# weighted PCA with FactomineR shows p.values = 0

Tags: pca

I have a problem concerning p.values when doing a PCA with the FactoMineR package in R. Note that the rows get weighted for the PCA (row.w), but in this case the p.values shown are all zero using the command:

```
res = dimdesc(res.mca, axes=1:2, proba=0.05)
```

So when I don’t use row weight, and want to see p.values, they all look “normal”. 
What am I missing? Why are there no p.values when I use a row weight?

Example with row weight:

```
asyFinanc
correlation 0.7561609       
p.value            0
```

Without row weight:

```
asyTransp
correlation 0.6899174   
p.value   1.138453e-21
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from the maker of the FactoMineR package, apparently one needs to divide the weight by the sum of itself to get p-values for a weighted PCA:

```
data(decathlon)    
res = PCA(decathlon[,1:10],row.w=(1:41)/sum(1:41))    
dimdesc(res)
```